# N-Players Gambler's Ruin ranking stability regarding stacks proportionality

Tags: statistics, markov-process

I'm interested in N-Player Gambler's Ruin game with `p = 0.5` and for each iteration :

- randomly pick two players
- make them exchange one chip

The result I'm interested in is the ranking probability of the players.
After running some simulations, it seems to me that for 3-player case considering chips stacks of `[5, 3, 2]` or `[50, 30, 20]`, the probability for each player to be ranked first, second or third is the same (the computation time is not).

Is it true that for N players the ranking probabilities will remain constant when multiplying the stacks by any strictly positive integer number ?

If so, can you point out a known result from which it can be deduced ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=2$, scaling the initial stack list by a positive integer factor doesn't affect the distribution of winning probabilities.

For $n > 2$, the winning probabilities are still unaffected by a scaling of the initial stack list.

To explain the invariance, choose a given player and regard the other $n-1$ players as a team. Then the invariance for $n=2$ implies the invariance for $n > 2$.

However for $n > 2$, we can't claim such invariance for ranks greater than $1$.

To demonstrate this, take $n=3$.

For a given initial stack list $X=[x_1,x_2,x_3]$, let $P_X$ be the $3{\times}3$ matrix whose $ij$-th entry $P_X[i,j]$ is the probability that player $i$ finishes with rank $j$.

Then for $X=[1,2,3]$ we get
$$
{\large{P_X}}
=
\pmatrix{
\dfrac{1}{6}
&\dfrac{259}{1182}
&\dfrac{121}{197}
\\
\dfrac{1}{3}
&\dfrac{241}{591}
&\dfrac{51}{197}
\\
\dfrac{1}{2}
&\dfrac{147}{394}
&\dfrac{25}{197}
\\
}
$$
whereas for $Y=[2,4,6]$ we get
$$
{\large{P_Y}}
=
\pmatrix{
\dfrac{1}{6}
&\dfrac{537964919}{2460583662}
&\dfrac{252086911}{410097277}
\\
\dfrac{1}{3}
&\dfrac{502077053}{1230291831}
&\dfrac{106039167}{410097277}
\\
\dfrac{1}{2}
&\dfrac{306154879}{820194554}
&\dfrac{51971199}{410097277}
\\
}
$$
Comparing $P_X,P_Y$, while the first column entries (the winning probabilities) are the same, the entries for the other columns (ranks $2$ and $3$), though numerically very close, are not the same.

As regards how the above matrices were computed, here's an example to illustrate the process . . .

Assume an initial stack list of $[a_0,b_0,c_0]$, where $a_0,b_0,c_0$ are positive integers with $b_0\le c_0$.

Let $s=a+b+c$.

For positive integers $a,b,c$ with $b\le c$ and $a+b+c=s$, let $p[a,b,c]$ be the probability that player $1$ finishes with rank $3$ (i.e., player $1$ is the first to tap out), given a current stack list of $[a,b,c]$.

For each such triple $a,b,c$ we have the equation
\begin{align*}
p[a,b,c]
=&\left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)\Bigl(\\[0pt]
&{\phantom{\left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)\Bigl(}}{\phantom{+}}\;\,p[a-1,b+1,c]+p[a+1,b-1,c]\\[0pt]
&{\phantom{\left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)\Bigl(}}+p[a-1,b,c+1]+p[a+1,b,c-1]\\[0pt]
&{\phantom{\left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)\Bigl(}}+p[a,b-1,c+1]+p[a,b+1,c-1]\\[0pt]
&{\phantom{\left({\small{\frac{1}{6}}}\right)}}\;\,\Bigr)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where on the $\text{RHS}$ we apply the substitutions
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
p[0,v,w]&=\,1\\[4pt]
p[u,0,w]&=\,0\\[4pt]
p[u,v,0]&=\,0\\[4pt]
p[u,v,w]&=\,p[u,w,v]\;\,\text{if $v > w > 0$}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
Thus we have a system of linear equations, one equation for each qualjfying triple $a,b,c$.

Then for an initial stack list of $[1,2,3]$ we get a system of $6$ linear equations in $6$ unknowns which yields
$$
p[1,2,3]=\frac{121}{197}\approx .6142131980
$$
and for an initial stack list of $[2,4,6]$ we get a system of $30$ linear equations in $30$ unknowns which yields
$$
p[2,4,6]=\frac{252086911}{410097277}\approx .6147002800
$$

Comment: Very thorough, thank you ! I can't check your probability matrixes right now because I just don't know how you got them. Out of curiosity did you use Swan 2006 (didn't read it yet) paper's method ?

Comment: @Pierre Mardon: I modeled it using systems of linear equation with variables for the relevant states. When I get a chance (probably tomorrow), I'll show the systems which I used to compute $P_X[1,3]$ and $P_Y[1,3]$.

Comment: @Pierre Mardon: A simulation with $10^9$ iterations (written in a fast language such as "C") will be sufficient to make it evident that $P_X[1,3] < P_Y[1,3]$.

Comment: Thanks for the computation detail !